# Array of string is empty and doesn't get set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following class  - Book with the following properties

```
var keyIdeas: [String]?
```

I have a function that initializes Book with data from the server:

```
init?(dict: NSDictionary) {
    let kIdeas = dict["keyIdeas"]  as? [String] ?? []
    self.keyIdeas = kIdeas
}
```

where I set self.keyIdeas = kIdeas, kIdeas is not empty, but the `self.keyIdeas` doesn't get set. It remains empty and causes the app to crash when I reference it.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So `self.keyIdeas` has the values of `dict["keyIdeas"] as? [String]`? Could you print it to ensure that? Also, how do you use your object? Are you sure it's the same occurence?

Comment: no self.keyIdeas is empty even though I try to set it to kIdeas. kIdeas has the value of dict["keyIdeas"]. When I print self.keyIdeas, it shows 0 values.

Comment: And if you print `dict["keyIdeas"]`, it's empty? And if you print `dict["keyIdeas"]  as? [String]`, it's nil?

Comment: As an aside, optional arrays can be confusing because they can be `nil`, non-nil and empty, or non-empty. Often there is no need to differentiate between empty and `nil`. In fact, this initialiser will always set `keyIdeas` to a non-nil value which raises the question why is the property optional. You will get an empty array assigned to `self.keyIdeas` if `dict` doesn’t have a “keyIdeas” entry, or if it is isn’t an array of `String`, or if it is an empty array of `String`.

Comment: You need to be very careful with terminology, `nil` and empty are two different states. You claim that `kIdeas` is not empty (which can only be true if `dict[“keyIdeas”]` is a non-empty array of `String`). You then claim that `self.keyIdeas` is not set (which means it remains `nil` which is literally impossible with the code you have shown). You then claim it (`self.keyIdeas`) “remains empty”. So now it has been set but is empty? Not all of these statements can be true simultaneously.

Comment: Could you make this into a reproducible example? Sounds to me like `dict["keyIdeas"]` either doesn't exist, has a value of another type or the value is an empty array. And what kind of crash do you get, could you share the line that crashes?

Comment: If you're getting NSDictionary "from the server," I'm strongly suspecting you're using JSONSerialization. You really want to avoid that. Switch to JSONDecoder, which is going to let you manage this much more carefully and get proper errors when you make mistakes, which it seems like is happening. (When you say "it remains empty and causes the app to crash when I reference it," referencing an empty array does not cause a crash, so I expect that you're doing something else that you'll need to show. But JSONDecoder is going to help here in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say exactly without seeing your full implementation.

However, here is a basic example - if you compare to your code, maybe you'll see what's not-quite-right:

```
class Book: NSObject {
    var keyIdeas: [String]?
    
    init?(dict: NSDictionary) {
        super.init()
        let kIdeas = dict["keyIdeas"]  as? [String] ?? []
        self.keyIdeas = kIdeas
    }
    func printIdeas() {
        print("inside Book class:", self.keyIdeas)
    }
}
```

and a view controller that creates / initializes an instance of `Book` ... tap anywhere to print to the debug console:

```
class BookTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    var myBook: Book!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let d: [String : Any] = [
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "myName",
            "keyIdeas" : ["a", "b", "c"]
        ]
        
        myBook = Book(dict: d as NSDictionary)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("VC getting property of myBook:", myBook.keyIdeas)
        myBook.printIdeas()
    }
    
}
```

What you should see:

```
VC getting property of myBook: Optional(["a", "b", "c"])
inside Book class: Optional(["a", "b", "c"])
```